Custom Logo: why parameters are not working at all?
I'm trying to use my custom logo, uploaded from Appearance > Header.
But none of the parameters I have set in my_custom_logo_setup are working.
In functions.php
//Add custom logo
    function my_custom_logo_setup() {
        $defaults = array(
            'height'               => 100, //not working!
            'width'                => 100, //not working!
            'flex-height'          => true, //not working!
            'flex-width'           => true, //not working!
            'header-text'          => array( 'site-title', 'site-description' ), //not working!
            'unlink-homepage-logo' => true, //not working!
        );
        add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', $defaults );
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_logo_setup' );

In header.php:
<header id="masthead" class="site-header site-title site-description">
    <div class="site-branding">
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'my_custom_logo_setup' ) ) {
            the_custom_logo();
        } ?>
        <h1 class="site-title">Titulo</a></h1>
        <p class="site-description">Description</a></p>
    </div>
    <!-- .site-branding -->

    <!-- <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
        
    </nav> -->
    <!-- #site-navigation -->

</header><!-- #masthead -->


in your theme you are testing for the existence of my_custom_logo_setup rather than the_custom_logo as is usual. Why?

well, I'm testing if my custom function (my_custom_logo_setup) exists, since I created it; I thought this would be the right way. Anyway, even if I change it to function_exists(the_custom_logo), the result is identical.

Otherwise I don't see anything unusual about your code. It might be some other code (plugin) interfering with it. Have you tried a later priority on after_setup_theme?

Could you explain me what means "later priority on after_setup_theme" ?

That would be add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_custom_logo_setup', 999 ); The last number is the priority. This means this action will be added after other actions. So if there is a plugin that also ads a custom logo, it will be overwritten by your code. But there could also be filters that override the logo.
